# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException caused either the beans interface or an advice on the bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Learning Spring, ran into something i can't figure out or find a reference to anywhere. Made a minimalistic project to filter out clutter and make things more clear: 1 package 6 files excluding pom.xml :

## 1 App.java - inside is the main() method.

```
package beantest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

public class App{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JavaConfig.class);

        ClassAAA aaa = (ClassAAA) context.getBean(ClassAAA.class);
        ClassBBB bbb = (ClassBBB) context.getBean(ClassBBB.class);

        aaa.doSomething();
        bbb.doSomething();
    }
}
```

## 2 ClassAAA.java

```
package beantest;

public class ClassAAA{
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("running 'doSomething()' by AAA object");
    }
}
```

## 3 ClassBBB.java - The Only Difference between ClassAAA and ClassBBB is that BBB implements InterfaceX.

```
package beantest;

public class ClassBBB implements InterfaceX{
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("running 'doSomething()' by BBB object");
    }
}
```

## 4 InterfaceX.java - NO METHODS, in this state.

```
package beantest;

public interface InterfaceX{
    //void doSomething();
}
```

## 5 JavaConfig.java

```
package beantest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class JavaConfig{

    @Bean 
    public ClassAAA aaa(){
        return new ClassAAA();
    }   

    @Bean
    public ClassBBB bbb(){
        return new ClassBBB();
    }

    @Bean
    public Aspect1 aspect1(){
        return new Aspect1();
    }
}
```

## 6 Aspect1.java

```
package beantest;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class Aspect1{

    @Before ("execution(* beantest.ClassAAA.doSomething(..))")
    public void beforeAAAdoesSomething(){
        System.out.println("##### BEFORE advice on AAA's doSomething() #####");
    }

    @Before ("execution(* beantest.ClassBBB.doSomething(..))")
    public void beforeBBBdoesSomething(){
        System.out.println("##### BEFORE advice on BBB's doSomething() #####");
    }
}
```

*** Running this gives the expected output of:

```
##### BEFORE advice on AAA's doSomething() #####
running 'doSomething()' by AAA object
##### BEFORE advice on BBB's doSomething() #####
running 'doSomething()' by BBB object
```

*** UNCOMMENTING the 'doSomething" method in InterfaceX.java and running gives the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'beantest.ClassBBB' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
    at beantest.App.main(App.java:12)
```

Why does running a method that is an implementation of an interface prevents Spring from finding the bean when said interface was never mentioned anywhere?

IF from here I am to comment-out the advice, in Aspect1.java, on ClassBBB

```
//@Before ("execution(* beantest.ClassBBB.doSomething(..))")
```

NO exception is thrown and the output is as expected:

```
##### BEFORE advice on AAA's doSomething() #####
running 'doSomething()' by AAA object
running 'doSomething()' by BBB object
```

AND FINALLY, changing

```
ClassBBB bbb = (ClassBBB) context.getBean(ClassBBB.class);
```

to

```
InterfaceX bbb = (InterfaceX) context.getBean(InterfaceX.class);
```

solves the issue with the advice and the interface method uncommented.

When should I ever look-up beans that implement an interface, by their class? I stumbled on this thing by mistake when experimenting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-proxying

> Spring AOP uses either JDK dynamic proxies or CGLIB to create the
>   proxy for a given target object. (JDK dynamic proxies are preferred
>   whenever you have a choice).
>
> If the target object to be proxied implements at least one interface
>   then a JDK dynamic proxy will be used. All of the interfaces
>   implemented by the target type will be proxied. If the target object
>   does not implement any interfaces then a CGLIB proxy will be created.

So basically, if your class has AN interface, spring will proxy it via that interface and thus to properly execute advice, you must reference the bean by Interface. If there is no interface, it will create a CGLIB proxy for the actual class and you can reference the bean by class.

You can override this default behavior and force CGLIB proxies and thus class-based advice by setting: `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)`

The javadoc of which states: "Indicate whether subclass-based (CGLIB) proxies are to be created as opposed to standard Java interface-based proxies."

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html

Comment: Thanks Ben, I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @user7175478 Please be sure to upvote this answer (as well as accepting, which you have already done) if it solved your problem.  BTW, your question is very well-written for a new StackOverflow user.  Kudos.

Comment: @JimGarrison, thanks Jim. Definitely up-voted the answer, but it doesn't show due to my noob status.